# Uni-modal vs Multi-modal models - how to pick best fit

Tags: python, model-fitting, gaussian-mixture-model

My goal is to create a model of a data distribution. I want to pick the best model however I am not sure how to compare the obtained models.

For uni-modal distribution I used the Fitter library. For multi-modal I tried Gaussian Mixture Models. Both models output aic/bic.

In Fitter the information criteria is computed [here](https://fitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/fitter/fitter.html#Fitter) (see _fit_single_distribution() method)
In GMM is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/mixture/_gaussian_mixture.py#L876)

In my case the values seem to have different orders of magnitudes:

- uni-modal - 1500-1600
- multi-modal (2 normal distributions) - 155000-157000

The original samples size used for fitting: ~16800 samples

**Single Distribution Fit Model**

[image: Uni-modal fit]

**Two Distribution Fit**
[image: Multi-modal fit]

**AIC/BIC values (multi-modal)**

I've picked 2 components in my example.
[image: AIC/BIC multi-modal]

Answer (score 0):

One way to compare the models is to use log likelihood.

For the GMM model I used this function to compute LL: `model.score(data)` where `model` is the output of the `fit()` function.

For the unimodal distribution I used this function to compute LL:

```
def loglik_unimodal(data, dist):
    _, x = np.histogram(data, bins=100, density=True)
    x = [(xx + x[i + 1]) / 2.0 for i, xx in enumerate(x[0:-1])]
    return np.mean(dist.logpdf(x))
```

`dist` is the fitted distribution e.g. `scipy.stats.lognorm(loc, scale)`